# initialize a multidimensional C array of variable size to zero

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I want to initialize a two-dimensional array of variable size to zero.
I know it can be done for a fixed-sized array:

```
int myarray[10][10] = {0};
```

but it is not working if I do this:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 10;
int myarray[i][j] = {0};
```

Is there a one-line way of doing this or do I have to loop over each member of the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot initialize it with an initializer, but you can `memset()` the array to 0.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  int a = 13, b = 42;
  int m[a][b];
  memset(m, 0, sizeof m);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note: this is `C99`.** In `C89` the declaration of m ( `int m[a][b];` ) is an error.

Comment: @vittorio88: you are probably using a C++ compiler. In C a pointer to any object (`m` alone, of type `int (*)[b]`) is compatible to a pointer to void (type `void *`) which is what `memset()` expects. So no problems there.

Answer (score 3):

[Online C99 Standard (n1256 draft)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), Section 6.7.8, para 3:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or **an object type that is not a variable length array type.**

Emphasis mine.

As everyone else has said, your best bet is to use `memset()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a pointer to your data structure, you could try [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/).

Comment: +1 - memset is by far the best way to initialise arrays and new memory allocations, it certainly works in C++ so is worth a try in C.

Comment: @kbrimington: In most contexts, an array name "decays" to a pointer to its first element. That works for multidimensional arrays too and, as memset() takes a `void*`, there's no issue about the type of pointer the array name by itself represents.

Comment: @pmg - Thanks. I understood this; however, I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @ChrisBD: In general, `memset` is not by far the best way to initialize data.  You should use it only if you have to.  It's often better to initialize with `{ 0 }` in C (or with `{ }` in C++) when possible.  It's more portable and less error-prone (it's easy to pass arguments to `memset` in the wrong order).

Comment: @james - risk of clerical error cannot be fairly used to justify "not by far the best way"; were it so, all procedures having greater than one parameter would be "by far not the best way" to accomplish a task. :) `memset` is an efficient procedure to accomplish the OP's requirement.

Comment: @kbrimington: `memset` is particularly error-prone because type-checking won't catch errors where the last two arguments are swapped. (Also, I'm more accustomed to a pointer argument being followed immediately by a size argument.) Anyway, that was only my secondary argument. (And I do agree that `memset` is the right thing to use in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a static array using non-constant variables.
Try using dynamic allocation:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 10;
size_t nbytes = i*j*sizeof(int);
int* myarray = (int*) malloc(nbytes);
memset(myarray,0,nbytes);
```

Comment: -0.5 (rounded up) in `C99` you **DO** can create static arrays using non-constant variables.

Answer (score -1):

Variable size two dimensional arrays are not supported in C. One dimension (i can't remember if it is first or second) has to be fixed. I recommend looping over it once it is defined.

Comment: -0.5 (rounded up) `C99` supports variable size two dimensional arrays.