# How to initialize an array[int][int] with zeros in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Picture this scenario. I need to store the quantity of products of a delivery. Each delivery and product has a number to identify it.
I am using an array somewhat like this: `int array[500][500];`

The main issue is that I do not have idea how to initialize the whole array with 0s. Any left-out junk in the 500 slots can backfire eventually in the many other algorithms I still have to code. I used to do `int array[500] = {0};` but in this case, there are two ID's related to each index.

Comment: `memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);` for an array named buf.

Comment: `int array[500][500]={{0}};` should work, I believe

Comment: @wildplasser That will zero the array, but it wouldn't be initialization.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3718716/1025391

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Is that some pedantic vocabulary intricacy?  If it zeros the array, it has the same effect as if it had been "initialized."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm just zeroing the first element of the first array.  When you initialize any element of an object, any other elements not explicitly initialized will be zeroed.

Comment: @ChristianGibbon If I may jump in, I suspect Robert was referring to your reply to wildplasser

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Indeed I came to that realization.  I had started a response to that and got side-tracked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Realizing you were referring to the other comment, the important thing there is that initialization comes at compile time.  Zeroing the array after the declaration would (unless the compiler recognized the intent and optimized) be done at run-time.  In the case of a a 500x500 matrix of 4-byte elements, that's a million bytes that need to be memset.  Does it matter?  I dunno, might be something to profile if anyone really cares.

Comment: The setting of bytes to zero has to happen at runtime regardless (except for `static` storage duration stuff) so I wouldn't expect any performance hit to be honest. That being said, I still do generally believe that we should be clear about the distinction between initialisation and assignment, because teaching this correctly has benefits down the line. Certainly I don't think it's helpful to write it off as "pedantic vocabulary intricacy".

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I would think global variables would be compile-time, as well.  But yes, I think I did get it mixed up a bit there.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Indeed, global variables have static storage duration. I didn't realise the OP's array is global?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: When C folks use the word "initialization," are they *always* referring to compile-time initialization?  This distinction doesn't seem to exist in other languages; Java calls it a "Compile-Time Constant," because  it must be declared `final` in order to be assigned at compile-time.  Consequently, I think of the general term "initialization" as simply meaning "setting an initial value."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not making a distinction between compile-time and run-time setting of values, only a distinction between initialising a thing (i.e. providing a value in the defining declaration) and later providing a value (including the case where there was _no_ prior initialisation that set a well-defined value). However it's possible that the rules here diverge from C++'s more than I realised?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: OK, I see what you're saying.  For what it's worth, Oracle (Java) defines "initialization" as "the first assignment of a variable," as class fields are often given their initial value in the constructor method.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 7):

> I used to do `int array[500] = {0};` but in this case there is two ID's related to each index.

Doesn't matter; that's still valid and appropriate in C11.

Try it and see!

#### [Live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a2a18fcdd49d6ee)

<sup>(Don't mind the ".cpp"; that's fixed for us by Coliru, but `-x c` tells GCC to compile the code as C.)</sup>

---

You do not need extra brackets. The standard spells this out explicitly:

> `[C11: 6.7.9/20]:`  If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the contained union. **Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.**

And later provides an example:

> `[C11: 6.7.9/26]:` EXAMPLE 3 The declaration
>
> ```
> int y[4][3] = {
>    { 1, 3, 5 },
>    { 2, 4, 6 },
>    { 3, 5, 7 },
> };
> ```
>
> is a definition with a fully bracketed initialization: 1, 3, and 5 initialize the first row of y (the array object `y[0]`), namely `y[0][0]`, `y[0][1]`, and `y[0][2]`. Likewise the next two lines initialize `y[1]` and `y[2]`. The initializer ends early, so y[3] is initialized with zeros. Precisely the same effect could have been achieved by
>
> ```
> int y[4][3] = {
>    1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7
> };
> ```
>
> The initializer for y[0] does not begin with a left brace, so three items from the list are used. Likewise the next three are taken successively for `y[1]` and `y[2]`.

Recall, by the way, that arrays are aggregates in C:

> `[C11: 6.2.5/21]:` Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.

Now, for the case of providing only one value (the 0), the normal rule you're used to (that all remaining elements take on zero anyway) still applies:

> `[C11: 6.7.9/21]:` If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

You may still receive style warnings from your compiler about this (I don't), but you can ignore them.

If you're using an antique version of C, though, you may need to double-up on your braces; I'm not too familiar with the history of this feature.

Comment: Nops: _warning: missing braces around initializer_ as @ChristianGibbons is pointing in comments the correct way is `int array[500][500]={{0}};` (anyway I'm not the not the downvoter)

Comment: @DavidRanieri I don't get that warning, and I don't see why one should get it, as the code is perfectly valid. See e.g. 6.7.9/26 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf (roughly C11). You don't need more braces; a flat sequence of initial values works just fine for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: In fact this is spelled out explicitly in 6.7.9/20.

Comment: I wish I had a copy of actual C11 and more time so that I could give proper references. Perhaps somebody else can finish this off.

Comment: I don't get you, in 6.7.9/26 the standard is quoting an initialization with double braces, and the warning is just telling you that: _missing braces_

Comment: `int array[500][500] = { 0 };` works fine with C11  (gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"my.d" -MT"my.o" -o "my.o" "../my.c")

Comment: @DavidRanieri Now read the rest of /26 too (it's only a few lines, shouldn't take you long), beginning _"Precisely the same effect could have been achieved by"_

Comment: @DavidRanieri "works fine with a warning" --> what warning, what compiler/options did you use?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you are totally right! get my upvote, another false positive of gcc? :(

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm compiling with `-pedantic` flag on on gcc 4.9.4: `warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces] int array[500][500] = {0};`

Comment: Some versions of GCC have generated the 'missing braces' warning; others don't.  Generally, the `= { 0 };` notation is allowed without warning (in modern GCC, say version 5 and later) — it's the 'universal initializer', valid for scalar integers as well as arrays and structures and arrays of structures and ...  You can probably ensure the 'missing braces' warning with an explicit `-W` flag — it may or may not be part of `-Wall` or `-Wextra` these days.

Comment: In C, just because you try something and it works doesn't necessarily mean it's valid.

Comment: With later versions of GCC, the 'missing braces' warning is suppressed for `= { 0 };` as the initializer sequence.  Try writing `= { 0, 0 };` and the warning is generated (legitimately).  The `-Wmissing-braces` option is enabled by `-Wall` in GCC (9.3.0 tested, but other versions too), but it doesn't trigger for the simple 'universal initializer'.

Answer (score 4):

If the sizes of the array are compile-time constants like the value 500 then it is enough to write

```
int array[500][500] = { 0 };
```

Or you can even use a designated initializer for example like

```
int a[500][500] = { [0][0] = 0 };
```

or like

```
int a[500][500] = { [0] = { 0 } };
```

or something similar.

In this case all elements of the array will be zero-initialized.

If it is a variable length array then you may not initialize it at declaration. In this case you can use the standard C function memset. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int main( void )
{
    size_t m = 500;
    size_t n = 500;

    int array[m][n];

    memset( array, 0, m * n * sizeof( int ) );
    //...
```

Comment: In your example, `memset( array, 0, m * n * sizeof( int ) );` can be simplified as `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);` This is one of the few examples of `sizeof` being computed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use `memset` to initialize the entire memory block to 0:

```
NAME         
   memset - fill memory with a constant byte

SYNOPSIS         
   #include <string.h>

   void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

DESCRIPTION         
   The memset() function fills the first n bytes of the memory area
   pointed to by s with the constant byte c.

RETURN VALUE         
   The memset() function returns a pointer to the memory area s.
```

So for your example:

```
int array[500][500];
memset(&array, 0, sizeof(int) * 500 * 500);
```

Comment: This is not initialization.

Comment: C has a specifics about _initialization_.  It is something done at the _definition_ of the variable.  What is here is a way to _assign_ the data.

Comment: Alternate to `memset(&array, 0, sizeof(int) * 500 * 500);` --> `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);`

Comment: Remove the `&` from `memset(&array, 0, sizeof(int) * 500 * 500)`. This expression can also be simplified as `memset(array, 0, sizeof array)`

Answer (score 0):

If your array is defined as a global variable or a `static` variable local to a function, you don't actually need to initialize it, all elements will have a zero value at program start.

If the array is defined inside a function body with automatic storage, `int array[500][500];`, you can initialize it at the point of definition with

```
int array[500][500] = { 0 };
```

If you mean to reset all values to zero at any point during program execution, you can use `memset` from `<string.h>`:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof array);
```